# How to create a union mount (bind two or more directories to one mountpoint) on illumos / solaris?

Tags: mount, solaris, illumos, union-mount

I have been using union mounts, such as `unionfs` on FreeBSD or `mergerfs` on Linux, and now I would need to do the same on illumos (SmartOS).

Reading [illumos](https://illumos.org/man/) or [SmartOS](https://smartos.org/man/) man pages is not helpful. Same with searching them [via external search engine](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fillumos.org%2Fman%2F).

If possible, how can one create a union mount (bind two or more directories to one mountpoint) on illumos / solaris?

If not possible, is there anything close to same effect?

### Why

In my humble opinion, union-like filesystems are used in relatively complex scenarios. Describing some here would be out of scope for this question. I would like to know if this is possible *a-priori* in any case, as I would not want an answer solving only a subset of all `unionfs` possible use-cases.

As an example: I need to pick and choose *from the subdirectories* of read-only zfs datasets, mounted DVD and readonly USB drives, overlaid with read-write datasets. The resulting mount point needs to be available as a cifs share. It would need to be done programmatically after boot, depending on various system factors.

For the interested, see referenced articles with some use cases. There are many such sysadmin scenarios.

---

[1] https://whattheserver.com/what-are-unionfs-mounts-and-how-to-use-them/

[2] https://medium.com/@knoldus/unionfs-a-file-system-of-a-container-2136cd11a779

Comment: Old SunOS4 had the Translucent File Service which do something like Linux unionFS but it was removed in SunOS 5.7 ie Solaris 7. So how to do something like it.  What happens if multiple zfs volumes have the same mountpoint as a property ?

Comment: How have you used the union mounts ? Why ? Usage case ? Hint: clones and snapshots of zfs volumes (and SunOS zones) replaces unionfs.

Comment: Ie the volumes have the same mountpoint assigned in theirs mountpoint property.

Comment: Clones of a zfs volume can be readonly.  One user = one clone of that volume.

Comment: You need to show a example of what you want to do. SunOS/Solaris /illumos is different and due to ZFS have other solutions (it is possible to have a lot of filesystems)

Comment: Thanks for your input. More details added.

Comment: Ok, example 2 is basically what snapshots of zfs volumes, clone of the snapshot and solaris zones does ie being able to use a clone of the normal system root volume as a local-dom system disk.  Your example of RO-media as backing store for read-write volumes, that is something else. I will have to think a little bit about that. Ask on the opencsw mailing list (one dist of OpenSolaris) ?

Comment: Thank you. I will ask on IRC as well.

Comment: `TFS` is probably the oldest similar implementation, as it is from January 1986. `TFS` was needed by `NSE`, the first distributed version control system. Since IBM and HP did not like to implement `TFS` in their OS, Sun developed `TeamWare` for working on `CDE`. Given that the `TFS` sources contain hints that it was a development payed by the US military, I guess this was the final reason for not porting it to Solaris even though this had been a minor effort. Anyway, attendees on the Sun User Group meeting in 1992 have been sad for that decision.

Comment: @schily: that is very interesting information. If you add it to an answer (basically saying it is not possible now, but it was in the past), I will accept it.